# To show number in million (M) by using custom format

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have to display Value 71,672,885 as 71.6M and I'm using below DAX

```
IF(Metric[EU]>=1000000,FORMAT(Metric[EU],"#,##0.0,,M")
```

But its showing value as 71,672,885.0 M. Let me know what I'm missing in above DAX function.

Note: Above function working perfectly in Excel but not in Power BI.

Answer (score 5):

The commas should be before the decimal place.

```
FORMAT(Metric[EU], "#,##,,.0M")
```

Here's the function reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function

Comment: Use `"#,#0,,.0M"` if you want to display `0.5M` instead of `.5M`.